# flexbox верстка

Tags: css3

Мне нужно выровнять блок вертикально и горизонтально по центру.
У меня выравнивание происходит только горизонтально. В чем проблема?

```
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: black;
}
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: дело в высоте `<body>`. Фоном оно заливается на всю высоту экрана, но по факту высота элемента `body` будет равна высоте его содержимого. Задайте  `min-height: 100vh`, должно помочь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Укажите размеры `body` или оберните в ещё один `div`:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: black;
}

.block {
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block">
  </div>
</div>
```